# How can i change the JTextArea string to something else

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

In my code i have made my JtextArea public and in my code i have called the jtextare and setTextArea however when i press that button because its a thread it doesnt allow me to change the JTextArea whenever my scanner works

```
 public void scan() throws InterruptedException {
    try {

        //This is the part i called it but doesnt change the jtextfield into getUid
        Login login = new Login();
        login.jTextField_username.setText(getUid);

        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
        System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

        CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

        System.out.println("Waiting for a card..");
        if (terminal == null) {
            return;
        }
        terminal.waitForCardPresent(0);

        Card card = terminal.connect("T=1");
        System.out.println("Card: " + card);
        System.out.println("Protocol: " + card.getProtocol());
        CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

        ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[]{(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00}));
        System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
        if (response.getSW1() == 0x63 && response.getSW2() == 0x00) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
        System.out.println("UID: " + bin2hex(response.getData()));

        getUid = bin2hex(response.getData());

    } catch (CardException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CardId.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better answers, create and post a valid [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Note that we cannot compile nor run a code snippet, and so any answer given will need to include guesses, but that being said, I think that the problem is that you have a faulty assumption here:

```
//This is the part i called it but doesnt change the jtextfield into getUid
Login login = new Login();         // **** A ****
login.jTextField_username.setText(getUid);  // **** B ****
```

At line **A** you create a new Login object, but is this the actual displayed object? I have a feeling that it's not, that you've already created and displayed the Login window, and are now creating a new one, one never displayed, and on line **B** are changing its state (the text held in one of its text components). If my guess is correct, then the better solution is to change the state of the actual displayed Login object, not a new and distinct one that you're creating in this method. How to do this? Impossible to state give the information that you've given so far.

If you want a more robust answer, then you will want to create and post a valid [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) in with your question -- please check out the link as it will explain all.

Other unrelated issues:

- Your question mentions `JTextArea`, but the code suggests that we're dealing with a `JTextField` -- which is it?
- Your question text suggests that you're mixing Scanner/console input with a Swing GUI. If this is so, I strongly urge you to not go this route, to get all input via the GUI. This will save you hours of debugging and frustration.

Comment: sorry yeah JTextField, and in line A i am just calling the GUI / class that the JTextField_username is in, and it is already displayed in the login window so i only want to change the value of it when i run the scan() function

Comment: Thanks for your insights!